# What is the meaning of "casket grey" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives

I read a sentence in a chapter named "Discovering Tut: the saga continues":

> Dark bellied clouds had scudded across the desert sky all day and now
>   were veiling the stars in **casket** grey.

Casket means a chest or any rectangular box.
But I'm not able to figure out the context in which it has been used.

Comment: The word "casket" describes the specific hue of this grey color. "As grey as a grey casket". The author might have meant some casket that the reader will imagine with ease. It could be a grey coffin, for instance. Maybe there is some widespread type of coffin of grey color that will easily come to mind upon reading this passage.

Comment: Google Books claims over five thousand written instances of [***lead** casket*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22lead+casket%22). Not to mention almost *eighty* thousand instances of [***leaden** sky*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22leaden+sky%22), which is all grist to the mill of this specific metaphoric usage. I'm not sure how well dense dark cloud cover fits in with a ***desert*** landscape, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the expressions "sky blue", "lily white", "blood red".

A colour that follows a noun, particularly a noun that indicates a material (or at least visible) object, indicates that it is the colour of that object.